# Parsing HTML -- why does this document have to parsed by text and not by tags?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using a Python module that scrapes a site and noticed in the below code that it handles different tables differently:

```
def player_stats(request, stat, numeric=False, s_index=False):
    """
    """

    supported_tables = ["totals", "per_minute", "per_poss", "advanced",
                        "playoffs_per_game", "playoffs_totals", "playoffs_per_minute",
                        "playoffs_per_poss", "playoffs_advanced"]

    if stat == "per_game":
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find("table", id="per_game")
    elif stat in supported_tables:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        comment_table = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and stat in x)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(comment_table, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find("table", id=stat)
    else:
        raise TableNonExistent
```

An example of the a page this would be used on: `https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/j/jamesle01.html`

If one were to do `soup.find_all("table")`, only the first table would be found.  The above code seems to check for "comments" in the HTML and then applies BeautifulSoup to that again.  I have a few questions:

1. Why aren't the other tables found?  They are also HTML tags (not commented out) so I'm struggling to understand the difference.
2. What is the `comment_table` line of code really doing? To me, it looks like it's checking for `text` attributes that are `NavigableString`s that contain an element in `supported_tables`?
3. If I'm right about the above, how does BeautifulSoup simply parse that block of text?  Is it "magic" or does that text have to be of a specific form...and we're, therefore, lucky in this case?

Let me know if you need more information to answer the questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. While they may appear to be HTML tags in the source of the page due to ease of read formatting, they are actually still within a commented block.

```html
<!--
    <table>
    ...
-->
```

is equivalent to

```html
<!--<table>...-->
```

Imagine lines and lines of code all forced into one line, not easy to read, and much easier to just put the comment tags on top of and below the code that is already formatted.

It might help to think about the "<--" as the block's id, so BeautifulSoup (and HTML renderers) don't see the code between the tags to render them.

2. That is exactly what it is doing. It finds the comment section that contains the item in the list, then parses that section as a separate HTML block (the next line) to find the table.
3. The text it receives from that line is a block of HTML code, without the comment indicator, so it treats it as any other normal HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on this but my observations:

1. Disable javascript in the browser and check again (just so not confused by what you see on page). I think the majority of tables are commented out. As mentioned in the other answer it may just be your difficulty in observing how the commenting is working but look for the ids where the text matches the supported_tables values, you will see these tables are still within wrapping comments.
2. The `comment_table` line is doing pretty much what you say. I would add, `supported_tables` is the expected list of commented out tables.
3. You will have returned [`bs4.element.Comment`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings) object as `comment_table`, rather than just a block of text; which `BeautifulSoup` knows how to parse.
   You can verify this with:

```
elif stat in supported_tables:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
    comment_table = soup.find(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString) and stat in x)
    print(type(comment_table))
```

`Comment` is a type of `NavigableString`.

Comment: Please comment as to how this is wrong. They are still commented out. It would help me to improve my answer

Comment: I upvoted.  Doesn't seem like you're wrong -- not sure what someone else might've seen wrong with it.